# Why does position: fixed, width: 100% element extend outside the viewport on iOS 8

Tags: html, ios, css, ios8

I have an element that is fixed to the top of the page, and scrolls with you when you scroll horizontally, the CSS is quite simple:

```
.thing {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  text-align: right;
}
```

You can see the it here: http://jsbin.com/cetutaxaju/1

Works fine on most browsers, but with Safari on iOS 8 this bar is not 100% of the viewport, but 100% of the content?! (it was fine on iOS 7)

The culprit seems to the meta viewport settings:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

As you can see when I take them out: http://jsbin.com/cetutaxaju/3

Does anyone know why this is happening, or even better how to fix it?

I need the viewport settings to remain as the real site does not work well without them.

Comment: try adding `right:0` to your class

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding **user-scalable=no** to your meta viewport settings? i.e.:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I had a similar issue and that fixed it for me.